# How to move cursor to top of the page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll

I'm using jQuery in my project. I have one `div` that's on the button of the page. I want to go to the top of the page when a user clicks on it.

I tried this but it goes to the bottom most position of the page:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

How can I go to the top of the page?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

For a nice walkthrough of how to use a button to make a page smoothly scroll back to the top with jQuery's `fadein()` and `fadeout()`, then check out [Smooth Page Scroll to Top with jQuery](http://gazpo.com/2012/02/scrolltop/)

It also has a live [demo](http://gazpo.com/downloads/tutorials/jquery/scrolltop/)

Answer (score 1):

The `scrollTo` function takes two parameters, x position and y position. Just set y position to zero.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```